# AngularJS and $document.height();?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

OK I'm trying to set a canvas height using `$document.height()` which works well as long as the content inside of it isn't angularJS generated as in a ng-repeat or any directive... 
I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PSqdHe4e9kqBvnbPGYbD?p=preview) to illustrate my point basically the canvas should have the same height as the document AFTER the ng-repeat renders...

```
angular.module('ngAppDemo', [])
.controller('ngAppDemoController', function ($scope, $window, $document) {
    $scope.canvas = angular.element('#spiro')[0];
    $scope.ctx = $scope.canvas.getContext("2d");
    $scope.canvas.height = $document.height();


    $scope.friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];

});
```

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things that are render dependent should be handled by a directive and not a controller. The controller should assign variables to the $scope, but the directive handles changes in the DOM directly.

To get changes to happen after AngularJS has finish digesting you can use $timeout. It's kind of like setTimeout in JavaScript except that it's executed after Angular finishes the current digest cycle. That means np-repeat will be executed, and then $timeout will be execute.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

So you might do something like this (not tested)

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.canvas = angular.element('#spiro')[0];
    $scope.ctx = $scope.canvas.getContext("2d");
    $scope.canvas.height = $document.height();
});
```

Comment: i know Dom manipulation needs to be done in a directive this was to elaborate a point:D thank you though $timeout is exactly waht i was looking for..... I'll accept the answer as soon as i can Ican't thank you enough!

Comment: @vimes1984 sometimes I've had to use 2 nested $timeout calls to get out of a digest cycle. Just remember if one $timeout doesn't work, then try two.